# Can i declare an Array once and through out the code declare it again?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, declaration

Can I re-declare an Array that is already declared?

So I am trying to go through a LinkedList and get every index which includes "null" as an Element and add those indexes to an array of ints.

The problem I have is : The array is already declared as:
int[] solution = new int[0];

Can i redeclare it once again like lets say:
int newSize = 10;
solution = [newSize];

Does that work?

```
int k = 0;
int counter = 0;

if(!isEmpty())
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < size(); j++)     
        {
            if(current.getContent().equals(null))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }

        result = new int[counter];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < size(); i++)
        {
            if(current.getContent().equals(null)) 
            {
                result[k++] = i ;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried printing out the elements of Result but all i get is well... an empty array.

Comment: If you have an array whose size changes than t is recommended to use java ArrayList.You can check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html link for more information about arraylist.

Comment: You can use [Arrays.copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)) to copy your array into a new array with a different size.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer (as mentionned on java documentation  => [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html))

> The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

Some more details:

When you use :
 `int[] solution = new int[0]`
you create an array that can hold 0 element and ask "solution" to refert to it.

If later on your code you use `solution = new int[10]` you will create an array that can hold 10 elements and ask "solution" to refer this new array.
The previous array still exists somewhere in the memory.

Search for "java memory management" if you want a full explanation.